# How to autocomplete a random URL with Regex?

Tags: php, html, regex

I need to create a password-manager and I do use php to get/post the informations. I created a Regex, to "autocomplete" an Url.

For Example, if there fill in "google", it should automatically add http://www. and at the end .com.

If you fill in www.google.com, it should just add http://, if you fill in google.com it should add https://www. and so on.

Do you guys know a better Regex or see any errors?

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th><?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $URL = $_POST["URL"];

            if (!preg_match("~^($)|(?:|f|ht)tps?://~i", $URL)) {
                $URL = "http://" . str_replace(' ', '', $URL);
            }

            if (!preg_match("~^($)|(www.)~i", $URL)) {
                $URL = "www." . str_replace('', '', $URL);
            }

            if (!preg_match("~^($)|(.ch$|.com$|.net$|.org$|.de$)~i", $URL)) {
                $URL = str_replace(' ', '', $URL) . ".ch";
            }

            if (!preg_match("[^A-Za-z0-9_.]", $URL)) {
                $URL = str_replace('www.http://', 'http://www.', $URL);
            }

            echo '<a href="' . $URL . '" id="link"> ' . $URL . ' </a>';
            } ?>
       </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use a simple substring search of the entered term against a catalog of known URLs and to always autocomplete to the full URL from the catalog if only a single match exists? Less cases, easier to implement.

Comment: you only add a `http://` instead of `https://`. This in conjunction with a "passwordmanager" makes me worry a bit.

Comment: `str_replace('', '', $URL)` shall do what?

Comment: when I input "www.google.at" I get `http://www.google.at.ch`. "api.google.ch" will result in `http://www.api.google.ch`. "www.myservice.ch/login" => `http://www.myservice.ch/login.ch`

Comment: I'd try to work with http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php instead. Via preg_match you have to many edge cases to think of.

Comment: Thank you for the informations so far, I'll see what I can do with it :D

Comment: sending passwords over http is not secure. Make your app default to https instead.

Comment: I have already changed it, thanks.